# Is current waveform of given dc-dc converter correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor

[image]

I don't understand how current (in continuous mode of operation ) at steady state is bounded for this dc-dc converter circuit.

What I thought qualitatively that current should keep increasing like this -[image]

**My analysis** was something like that -

At t=0 ;

We close the switch and initially inductor has zero intial current ,and after that current keep increasing and reaches to some value
$$I1max$$
and at that instant we open the switch which causes inductor current to decay through resistive load and reaches to a value
$$I1min$$
and then again switch closes and again current of inductor rises and  just before opening of switch current will be
$$I2max$$

**BUT**

$$I2max > I1max $$

Because this time inital condition is I1min while previously it was zero ,and hence we can say that as time passes initial condition keep increasing and which causes current to increase in every cycle and hence it become a  unbounded function!

But whatever I analysed is not what actually happens so where did I make mistake in my analysis ? Or this waveform is not correct?

Comment: the snap you have added is for steady state. Initially current will increase as you said dc-dc converters will have feedback which controls both the voltage and current.

Comment: @user19579 but what I have drawn that includes transient response as well

Comment: What you have shown here, is a well known topology in designing DC-DC Converters; it is a buck converter which works with a feedback control loop to keep Vout constant. At steady state, when the switch is closed the inductor charges with the following equation: Il=(Vin-Vout/L)*t, and Ipeak=(Vin-Vout/L)*Ton. Since Vin,Vout,  L and Ton  are constants it means Ipeak is the same for each cycle and will not increase. When the switch is opened, Il=(-Vout/L)*t, Imin=(-Vout/L)*Toff, and since Vout, L and Toff are constants, Imin should be constant and not varying.

Comment: @learn design thanks ! So it means that  this circuit is incomplete without feedback control loop and if there will be no control loop then what I analysed was actually true (i.e current keep on increasing after every cycle)?

Comment: @user215805, No, focus on the equations, All the parameters are constants. The current increases if Ton increase and Toff decreases. You should understand that the analysis is done in steady state and not in transient state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you have made is that you have assumed that the **peak** current will rise linearly with time (at the end of each charging cycle) and for all time. It won't because of the load resistor; it ultimately limits the current to a maximum value: -

$$I_{0(pk)} = \dfrac{V_S}{R_{LOAD}}$$

You physically cannot get a load current higher than the above.

Comment: Thanks Andy ! Actually I didn't assume it rises linearly rather it is just my poor drawing skill that make it look like that ,I know it increases like[ V (1-exp(R/L)+zero input response ] but still Zero input response keep changing in each cycle with change in initial condition , and also isn't  Imax=Vs/R is valid only for LTI R-L circuits ? But here it is non linear circuit

Comment: I'm saying you can't get physically higher than Vs/R.

Comment: Is there any way that we can proof that current will be a bounded function ?

Comment: I thought I'd done just that. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: A differential equation solution to show how it actually settle   or  a qualitative analysis at least for 2-3 cycle to show that current actually tending to certain maximum limiting  value

Comment: Just use a simulator. Dead easy. Anyway, are we done with this question now?

Comment: @user215805 are we done with this question now?

Comment: @+1,I realized that you were partially correct that current (I) cannot grow beyond V/R , but it is not necessary that current will ultimately reach to V/R ,   [" it ultimately limits the current to a maximum value" ]so I found that sentence confusing , could you improve it so that I'll accept your answer !

Comment: @user215805 my answer says the current will be limited to a maximum value and, underneath those words I gave the formula (V/R). Isn't that what you are asking me to do? I'm all for improving the answer but I can't get my head around what you see that is confusing.

Comment: @ I'll accept your answer but hopefully you'll tell ,between what max and min values (in terms of duty cycle) current vary at steady state which would be useful for other users as well .

Comment: @user215805 I'm really trying to figure out what you mean. Here's my guess: the duty cycle on time determines how much energy/current is accumulated in the inductor. Current rises linearly with time when charging the inductor but only initially because as current is rising, the load resistor voltage also rises and this ultimately limits the maximum current. If you had an output capacitor across the resistor (as per a standard buck circuit) it'll be a different story entirely because the capacitor will keep Vout nearly constant over the full cycle. Maybe this is what you mean?

Comment: isn't this configuration is very similar to square full wave inverter with R-L load (with only two slight difference 1.voltage across R-L is either Zero or V while in full wave inverter it is V or -V  2.In square full wave inverter in books duty cycle is generally 1/2 while in this case it is not 1/2, that's why similar to full wave inverter -in this case also current should vary between some max and min values of current at steady state that is why I thought you would mention what those max and min values would be at steady state

Comment: I’m not seeing the similarity unfortunately.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/full-bridge-inverter   please take a look of current waveform , hopefully you'll understand my concern !

Comment: The current waveform looks like a standard resistor inductor charging waveform so, I’m not sure what you want me to add other than, it appears to coincide with my earlier thoughts.